# Understanding a theorem from "Probability theory of Banach Spaces " book.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, banach-spaces

[image]

[image]

I don't understand the proof after "The hypothesis of the theorem indicate...... , can someone kindly explain it for me . 
Thanks :)